# list transition for react isnt showing due to an error

Tags: reactjs, components

Im New to react.

Im trying to implement this into my react app. 
https://github.com/trungdq88/react-router-page-transition/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md

Now i dont want it to show on my home page like the example but in my "MyStories" component  when you navigate to that component . But it seems i  did something wrong and now im recieving this error.

Uncaught Error: MyStories.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

heres my code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import Layout from './components/Layout';
import Profile from './components/Profile';
import MyStories from './components/MyStories';
import NewStory from './components/NewStory';
import PageTransition from 'react-router-page-transition';
import DetailPage from './components/DetailPage';



class Root extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path='/' component={Layout}>
          <IndexRoute component={Layout} />
          <Route path="/MyStories" component={MyStories}/>
          <Route path="/profile" component={Profile}/>
          <Route path="/NewStory" component={NewStory}/>
          <Route path="/detail/:itemId" component={DetailPage} />
          </Route>


  <Route path="/detail/:itemId" component={DetailPage} />
      </Router>
    )
  }
}

export default Root;


import 'babel-polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import Root from './Root';





let reactAppRender = (element) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Root browserHistory={browserHistory}/>,
    element
  );
};



$(function() {
  let reactApp = document.getElementById('app');
  if (reactApp) {
    reactAppRender(reactApp);
  }
});

import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router';

export default React.createClass({
  render() {
    return
    <div className="transition-item list-page">
        {this.state.items.map(item => (
          <Link
            key={item.id}
            className="list-item"
            to={`/detail/${item.id}`}
          >
            <Item {...item} />
          </Link>
        ))}
      </div>
  }
})

import React from 'react';

import { Link } from 'react-router';
import PageTransition from 'react-router-page-transition';

class Layout extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
          <h1>Welcome </h1>
          <ul role="nav">
              <li><Link to='/'>HOME</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/profile">Profile</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/mystories">MyStories</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/newstory">NewStory</Link></li>



          </ul>
          <PageTransition>
            {this.props.children}
          </PageTransition>

        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Layout;

import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

export default class DetailPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="transition-item detail-page">
        <Link to="/">Back</Link>
        <h1>
          Detail {this.props.params.itemId}
        </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: All my code isnt showing for some reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The component above `Layout` has a `render()` method with a `return` in one line, but what you want to return starts in the line below it:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router';

export default React.createClass({
  render() {
    return
    <div className="transition-item list-page">
        {this.state.items.map(item => (
          <Link
            key={item.id}
            className="list-item"
            to={`/detail/${item.id}`}
          >
            <Item {...item} />
          </Link>
        ))}
      </div>
  }
})
```

When this happens, wrap the JSX component in parenthesis:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router';

export default React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="transition-item list-page">
        {this.state.items.map(item => ( //Incidentally, you reference this.state here but your component has no state
          <Link
            key={item.id}
            className="list-item"
            to={`/detail/${item.id}`}
          >
            <Item {...item} />
          </Link>
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

You did this in the other components, you might have just missed this one.

For the future: if you get an error along the lines of `Uncaught Error: MyStories.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned.` look at return statement of the render method of the component that the error is mentioning (in this case, MyStories). Remember, for now you can only return JSX from the render method of a React component.

Comment: sorry to ask but can you show me what you mean so im sure?